# The relationship of derived subgroup and absolute center of a group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Questions:
For any group $G$, the absolute center $L(G)$ of $G$ is defined as
$$L(G) = \lbrace g\in G\mid \alpha(g)=g,\forall\alpha\in Aut(G)
\rbrace,$$ where $Aut(G)$ denote the group of all automorphisms of
$G$. Observe that $L(G)\leq Z(G)$, where $Z(G)$ denotes the center of group $G$. I want to find an example of a finite non-abelian $p$-group $G$ with cyclic center such that $G^{\prime}<L(G)<Z(G)$. that is $G^{\prime}$ is a proper subgroup $L(G)$ and $L(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $Z(G)$, where $G^{\prime}$ is the  derived subgroup of $G$.

I have tried the following example:
$$G=\langle x,y| x^{p^{n-1}}=y^p=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{1+p^{n-2}}\rangle,   (n\geq 4). $$ 
Observe that $G$ is of class 2, $\Phi(G)=Z(G)=\langle x^p\rangle \simeq C_{p^{n-2}}$ and $G/G^{\prime}\simeq C_{p^{n-2}}\times C_p$. Therefore  $|G^{\prime}|=p$. I tried and found there no examples or order $2^n$ with $n\leq 8$ and $3^n$ with $n\leq 7$. For large values of $n$, GAP is not answering.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I did a computer calculation, and there are no examples of order $2^n$ with $n \le 8$ or $3^n$ with $n \le 7$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have tried the following example:
$$G=\langle x,y| x^{p^{n-1}}=y^p=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{1+p^{n-2}}\rangle,   (n\geq 4). $$ 
Observe that $G$ is of class 2, $\Phi(G)=Z(G)=\langle x^p\rangle \simeq C_{p^{n-2}}$ and $G/G^{\prime}\simeq C_{p^{n-2}}\times C_p$. Therefore  $|G^{\prime}|=p$.

Comment: Representation matters: if you have an fp-group, GAP will work slower with it than with a pc-group. You can use [IsomorphismPcGroup](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap46.html#X873CEB137BA1CD6E) for conversion. I recommend to see also [this](https://blogs.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/codima/files/2016/10/CoDiMa2016_Linton.pdf) by Steve Linton.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest group $G$ with cyclic center for which $G'<L(G)<Z(G)$ is $G:=\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$, which is a finite $p$-group for $p=2$, as
$$G'=0,\qquad L(G)=2\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z},\qquad Z(G)=\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Sorry...I missed the non-abelian condition in my question. I have corrected my question. I need the example of a non abelian finite $p$-group.

Comment: Please do not change questions that have been correctly answered.

Comment: The above answer is in case of abelian group. Actually I am working on a problem of finite non-abelian  $p$-group. I tried it a lot but could not find  example. There is one result that If $G$ is an extraspecial $p$-group. Then (1) $L(G)$ is a cyclic group of order 2 if $p=2$ and (2) $L(G)=1$ if $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: If $G$ is extraspecial then $Z(G)\cong\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ by definition, so the strict inclusions $G'<L(G)<Z(G)$ obviously cannot hold.